# how to give a NumPy array to a model as input with a predefined shape

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to give a NumPy array as input to a model with a predefined shape but am getting a type error in TensorFlow Keras:

```
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32)' with type '<class 'tuple'>'
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
  num_blocks=4
  num_filters=32
  num_outputs=1,
  d1=128, 
  d2=128, 
  word_size=32, 
  ks=3,
  depth=5, 
  reg_param=0.0001, 
  final_activation='sigmoid'
  #Input and preprocessing layers
  inp = Input(shape=(num_blocks * word_size * 2,));
  df=pd.read_csv('sm4_dataset.csv')
  df1=pd.read_csv('sm4_datainputs.csv')
  X=df.to_numpy()
  Y=df1.to_numpy()
  model.fit(X,Y,epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `word_size` to be a tuple with the single value `32` in it, because your assign statement has a comma at the end of it (syntax for a tuple).

When you multiply a tuple by a number (in your case, `4 * (32,) * 2`), it repeats the tuple that many times. That's why your shape is a tuple of `(32,)` repeated 8 times, instead of `256`.

Don't end your assign statements with commas unless you want them to be tuples instead of numbers.